# R Function to Subset, Aggregate, Pivot, and Save Data Frames

Tags: r, function, dataframe, syntax

I am having trouble writing a function:

I have a df that I would like to (a) `subset`, keeping only the needed columns, (b) `aggregate` values for 'x' based on two grouping variables ('date' and 'urban'), (c) `pivot_wider`, and (d) `write.csv`. Ultimately, I need to do this for 14 variables and two grouping parameters, which I though would be a good time to use a user-defined function.

Here is sample data:

```
> print(head(data, 5))
# A tibble: 5 x 23
    fn    zip5   group cluster area    fy  week   date      urban   FN0   FN1
  <int>   <dbl> <chr> <fct>   <ord> <dbl> <fct> <date>     <ord>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 584000   NA    1    LOCAT~   Nort~  2019 00B   NA         urba~    3    NA
2 584000   NA    1    LOCAT~   Nort~  2019 01B   2018-09-29 urba~    20   37
3 584000   NA    2    LOCAT~   Sout~  2019 02B   2018-10-06 rura~    5    3
4 584000   NA    2    LOCAT~   Sout~  2019 03B   2018-10-13 rura~    NA   NA
5 584000   NA    3    LOCAT~   East~  2019 04B   2018-10-20 subu~    13   19
```

And here is `dput()`:

```
> dput(droplevels(wkhr4_W[2282334:2282341, c("fn", "date", "urban", "FN2")]))
structure(list(fn = c(150929L, 150929L, 150927L, 150927L, 150927L, 
150927L, 150927L, 150927L), date = structure(c(18412, 18419, 
NA, 17803, 17810, 17817, 17824, 17831), class = "Date"), urban = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Suburban", "Not Avaliable"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), FN2 = c(1625, 1911, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
save_file = function(x, y, data) {
  file <- print(paste0("wkhr_2020_", x, "_", y))
  df <- subset(data, date >= "2020-01-04" & date <= "2020-06-06", select = c(date, fn, y, x))
  file <- aggregate(as.formula(paste(x, "~ date +", y)), FUN = sum, data = df)
  file <- pivot_wider(file, values_from = x, names_from = y)
  write.csv(file, paste0("./Work Hours/", file, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}

save_file("FN0", "urban", data)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you be willing to provide a sample of `data` so you can get an optimal answer? Try using `dput(head(data))` and edit question with output.

Comment: Your `x` and `y` won't be evaluated in the formula for aggregate - try `aggregate(as.formula(paste(x, "~ date +", y)), ...)` instead. I'd also strongly recommend including `data` as an argument so that you can use it on any data frame regardless of whether it is named `data`.

Comment: @Ben - Thanks for the advice. I cannot post the data (in any form) because of company policy, but I added an edited version of `head(data, 5)` output to my question.
@GregorThomas - I changed the code in the post to reflect your suggestions. The code now gives an error:  Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x The columns `8` and `1` don't exist.

Comment: Would you please share your edited data with `dput`? It makes it much easier to copy/paste it. If your factors have a lot of levels, `dput(droplevels(data[1:10, ]))` works well.

Comment: @GregorThomas - Frustratingly, I cannot post the `dput()` output because it would include proprietary data. Company policy.

Comment: In that case, can you please construct some similarly structure sample data and post it with `dput()`? It's hard to help you without anything to test on, and it's annoying to import the data you posted in the format you've used.

Comment: I'd also note that we don't need any of the columns that aren't used... probably posting the `FN0`, `urban`, `date`, and `fn` columns would be enough. I'm not really asking for more information than is already in the question, just a friendlier format. `dput(droplevels(data[1:10, c("fn", "date", "urban", "FN0")]))`

Comment: @GregorThomas - I appreciate the help. Let me work on getting you something.

Comment: Alternatively, you may be able to narrow the problem down more yourself. My first step will be to name the sample data `data`, set `x <- "FN0"`, `y <- "urban"`, and run your code one line at a time, checking the results at each step. Since  my `aggregate` recommendation changed your error, the function is at least getting that far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your in your `subset` line - `select = c(date, fn, y, x)` is mixing `date` and `fn` (which are literal, unquoted column names) and `y, x` which are objects whose values are column names. You can't mix and match like that. Changing to `select = c("date", "fn", y, x)` resolves the issue.

In recent-ish versions of `pivot_wider`, you should use `all_of()` to work with objects whose values are column names, so I made that change too.

Lastly, you began by constructing the file name and calling it `file`, but then overwrote that also calling your  modified data `file`. I keep `df` for the data, and `file` for the file name. I also changed your `print()` to `message()`, it can be friendlier in certain cases, like if you ever want to mute it without changing the function, and it will probably print in a different color, which can make it easier to scan for.

```
save_file = function(x, y, data) {
  file = paste0("wkhr_2020_", x, "_", y)
  message(file)
  df <- subset(data, date >= "2020-01-04" & date <= "2020-06-06", select = c("date", "fn", y, x))
  df <- aggregate(as.formula(paste(x, "~ date +", y)), FUN = sum, data = df)
  df <- pivot_wider(df, values_from = all_of(x), names_from = all_of(y))
  write.csv(file, paste0("./Work Hours/", file, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```